# C++ namespaces trobles

Tags: c++, namespaces

```
//portl.cpp
namespace FAWN {
namespace Sys{

class PortListner {

....
Connecter::ConPtr _cur_con; - the main problem is here
```

...

```
//con.cpp
namespace FAWN {
namespace Sys {

class Connecter {

.....
public:

 typedef boost::shared_ptr<Connecter> ConPtr;
```

...

Moreover, portl.cpp file is included into some other "main" sourse file. And this "other-main" file includes con.cpp too. So if I include con.cpp to portl.cpp - I define Connecter twice (in portl and in main). If I do not include it, compilator doesn't know what Connecter::ConPtr (or FAWN::sys::Connecter::ConPtr) means and try to use it as defenition of method.

Comment: You're including `.cpp` files in other `.cpp` files? Do you have header files? Also, what are the actual errors?

Comment: Try to put more effort into your question the next time (or, even better, you can edit it). Use the "Code" button to format code and not "Quote", also even if English is not your first language make an effort to explain yourself as best as you can; right now your question is not easy to understand.

Comment: 1>d:\dv\proj\serv\1\portlistner.h(9) : error C2653: Connecter: не является именем класса или пространства имен
1>d:\dv\proj\serv\1\portlistner.h(9) : error C2146: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед идентификатором "_cur_con"
1>d:\dv\proj\serv\1\portlistner.h(9) : error C4430: отсутствует спецификатор типа - предполагается int. Примечание. C++ не поддерживает int по умолчанию
1>d:\dv\proj\serv\1\portlistner.h(9) : error C4430: отсутствует спецификатор типа - предполагается int. Примечание. C++ не поддерживает int по умолчанию

Comment: For the Cyrillically disinclined: "error C2653: Connecter: is not a class or namespace name", "error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier '_cur_con'", "error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `class Connecter` (which you should probably rename to `Connector`) into a header file (`.h` instead of `.cpp`) and add include guards into the file. That is, at the beginning of your `con.h` file, add lines

```
#ifndef CON_H_INCLUDED
#define CON_H_INCLUDED
```

and at the very end, add the line

```
#endif
```

This way, even if you `#include` `con.h` twice, the second time it will not get read because the symbol `CON_H_INCLUDED` has been defined on the first time so the `#ifndef-#endif` pair hides the content.

This is the common way in C++: put class declarations in `.h` files that get `#include`d in `.cpp` files that then actually define the functions.

Comment: I've already splited up my sourses into definition and decloration (I hope it's called this way in English).
The main troble is that I NEED to include it in portlistner.h - or it won't find Connector (thanks... I'll change) as a class at all. And tells me, that Connector is not a namespase, or class-name.

Comment: Did you add the include guards? Because after adding those you can then include `con.h` into your `portl.cpp` (or that's probably `portl.h` if you've split the declarations out) without having a double definition even if you later include `con.h` again in a file where you've included `portl.h`.

Comment: I've been writing a long comment full of thanks but internet turned off and though it away..

Thanks for jk, Igor Zevaka and goldPseudo.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it should look:

```
#ifndef PORTAL_H
#define PORTAL_H
#include "con.h"
//portl.h
namespace FAWN {
namespace Sys{

  class PortListner {

....
    //might need to specify Connector's namespace  fully here
    FAWN::Sys::Connecter::ConPtr _cur_con; 
...
  };
}
#endif //PORTAL_H

//con.h
#ifndef CON_H
#define CON_H
namespace FAWN {
namespace Sys {

  class Connecter {

  .....
  public:

    typedef boost::shared_ptr<Connecter> ConPtr;

  };
}
#endif //CON_H
```